# Consider the following binary operation on $\mathbb Z_{≥0}$: $f(a, b) = |a − b|$. Is $(\mathbb Z_{≥0}, f)$ a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to check the associativity (1), identity (2), and inverse (3).

1. $||a-b|-|c||=||a|-|b-c||$;
2. $|a-e|=|e-a|=|a|$;
3. $|a||a^{-1}|=|a^{-1}||a|=e$.

Here are what I got for now but I don't feel that's a right proof.

Comment: so you think it is a group or not?

Comment: Associativity should be $||a - b| - |c|| = ||a| - |b - c||$, and it shouldn't be just stated, but it should be proven! Or, perhaps more relevantly, a counterexample should be found. Similarly, with identity, you need to nominate the identity. You need to tell us what $e$ is equal to. Is $e = 0?$ Or maybe $1$? Maybe $112$? If you want to prove the existence of an identity, you need to figure out which of the elements of the set $\Bbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ it is, then prove $|a - e| = |e - a| = a$.

Comment: Here is such a counterexample $1*(2*3)=1*|2-3|=1*1=|1-1|=0$ whereas $(1*2)*3=|1-2|*3=1*3=|1-3|=2$. You don't need to go further...

Comment: This cannot be a group by e.g. $f(a,b)$ is not necessarily injective for $b$ once $a$ is fixed.

Answer (score 5):

1. Associativity:

We must verify that $\forall a$, $b$, $c \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, that:

$$f(f(a,b), c) = f(a, f(b, c))$$

To this end, we just lay out the expression:

$$f(f(a,b), c) = \lvert \lvert a - b\rvert - c\rvert = \lvert a - \lvert b - c \rvert\rvert = f(a, f(b,c))$$

Can you prove (or disprove) this?

(**Answer if you get stuck**:)

We give a particular counterexample. Assume that $a > b > c > 0$ so that $\lvert a - b\rvert = a - b$ and $\lvert b - c\rvert = b - c$. Then we have that:

$$f(f(a,b), c) = \lvert \lvert a - b\rvert - c \rvert = \lvert (a - b) - c\rvert$$

$$f(a, f(b,c)) = \lvert a - \lvert b - c\rvert \rvert = \lvert a - (b - c) \rvert$$

So associativity of $f$ in this case boils down to saying:

$$\lvert (a-b) - c \rvert = \lvert a - (b-c) \rvert$$

For a concrete example of this, choose $a = 5$, $b = 3$ and $c = 1$.

$$\lvert \lvert 5 - 3\rvert - 1\rvert = 1$$

$$\lvert 5 - \lvert 3 - 1\rvert \rvert = 3$$

Notice that my choice of counterexample is to demonstrate this: this is NOT true because subtraction is NOT associative for real numbers, let alone non-negative integers (i.e. $(a - b) -c \neq a - (b - c))$. So $f$ is NOT associative because it fails for a particular subset of non-negative integers.

2. Identity

By definition of identity, it is an element $e$ such that $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$:

$$f(a, e) = \lvert a - e\rvert = \lvert e - a\rvert = f(e,a) = a$$

Can you show what non-negative integer $e$ satisfies this equation (if any)?

(**Answer if you get stuck**)

Take $e = 0$ and $e \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ and $f(a,e) = f(e,a) = a$. So $(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}, f)$ has identity.

3. Inverse

For any element $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, the inverse of $a$ is the element $a'$ such that:

$$f\left(a, a'\right) = \lvert a - a'\rvert = \lvert a' - a\rvert = f\left(a', a\right) = e$$

(where $e$ denotes the identity element if it exists)

Can you find a non-negative integer $a'$ such that the above equation is satisfied (if any)?

(**Answer if you get stuck**)

We verified that the identity $e$ exists, and it is $0$. So just plug this into the above equation and we get that:

$$f(a,a') = 0 \;\mathrm{iff}\; \lvert a - a' \rvert = 0$$

By definition of absolute value, $a = a'$. So $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, $a$ is its own inverse.

(**Conclusion**)

Our conclusion is that $\left(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}, f\right)$ is NOT a group because $f$ fails to be associative.

Comment: "We give a particular counterexample." I like almost all of this answer, but this statement is just untrue. You should give specific numbers for $a, b, c$, like [Jean Marie](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4373644/consider-the-following-binary-operation-on-z%e2%89%a50-fa-b-a-%e2%88%92-b-is-z%e2%89%a50-f-a#comment9139026_4373644) did.

Comment: @TheoBendit My bad. I realized that the conditions I gave to generate this counterexample are just flat out incorrect. It should have been strict inequalities in my counterexample because the "associativity" holds for the cases when all of $a,b,c$ are equal, and when $c = 0$ (among other ways this equality could hold). Thank you for pointing out my mistake, I will edit it.